# Documentation for Gmail API error handling

Tags: gmail-api

I tried to find documentation for Gmail API error handling, something similar to [this Drive API page](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/handle-errors), but I couldn't find anything. Can anyone help me find all relevant errors that the API can return and perhaps what is the best way to handle them.

Thanks

Comment: I don't think there is an error guide like that one for the Gmail API, but errors from Google's REST APIs are very similar. I think you can get a lot from the guide you linked. Are you interested in some particular errors?

Comment: Not really, I just wanted to be sure that I covered all cases and in the best way possible. Thanks anyway.

Comment: As Tholle said, there may be no error handling guide. But as for documentation, example is this [Usage Limit](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/quota) there is a given response like: "Exceeding a rate limit will cause an HTTP 403 or HTTP 429 Too Many Requests response and your app should respond by retrying with exponential backoff." this will help you create your error handling functions. It will also be seen in some pages of the document for Gmalo API. Hope this helps!